# Pass object parameter to stored procedure by SqlHelper

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlhelper

I have a SQL table like this:

[image: Table]

`ID` is Identity column.

And I have a class for this table in ASP.Net project like this:

```
public class Topic
    {
        public int ModuleID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BodyHTML { get; set; }
    }
```

Also I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addTopic] 
    @Topic dbo.Topic READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    insert into OnlineHelp_Topic
    select * from @Topic
END
```

I want to pass a `Topic` object from project and execute this stored procedure by SqlHelper.

I read many post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440832/passing-an-object-collection-as-a-parameter-into-sql-server-stored-procedure) and create a `User-Defind Table` in SQL Server and I test this code:

```
Topic Topic = new Topic()
            {
                BodyHTML = "test body",
                ModuleID = 1000,
                Name = "test"
            };
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnection"].ConnectionString;
int rowsAffected = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(constr, "addTopic", new SqlParameter("@Topic", Topic));
```

But this code has error in `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(...)` like this;

[image: Error]

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SqlHelper` but I would think you'd need to pass the UDT data in a `DataTable` or at least some type of collection.  Also there should be a way to tell it the query type is a stored procedure.

Comment: @Mahdi I added error.

Comment: take a look to this other question, it might give you some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure ... basically, you'll need to create the list object so you can query it from the sp

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the topic parameters like follows:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ModuleID ", topic.ModuleID ));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", topic.Name));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BodyHTML", topic.BodyHTML));
int rowsAffected = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(constr, "addTopic", parameters.ToArray());
```

You will also need to modify your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a DataTable as parameter
example

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(constr, "addTopic", new SqlParameter("@Topic", TopicDatatable));
```

The DataTable must have the same columns: names and datatypes of the User Defined Table Type.