# C# Entity Framework - How to generate object type for input parameters of stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that gets many input parameters (the procedure persoms Insert statement)

I use EF to access this procedure.

Is there a way to automatically generate object type that contains all the input parameters of the procedure?

Something like the complex type that is being generated for the output of the procedure.

My EF version is 6.1.3

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take 12 separate parameters and send them as a single object to the stored procedure? The goal of your question is unclear.

Comment: Not marking as a duplicate because it doesn't use EF, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11440917/1195056) shows a way to do it with a straight database connection. EF gives you that option as well through the `context.Database` property. Keep an eye on the comments that say you may need to use a `List<T>` instead of a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible to automatically generate a class for the input parameters of a stored procedure in EF 6.1.3.